# Execute node JS code in Google apps script

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, encryption, cryptojs

I want to run the following NodeJS code in Google app script

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
let timeStamp_nonce = Date.now().toString();
let bodystring = `{"ID":"001"}`
const body = JSON.parse(bodystring)
const secret = "secret"
const msg= {
    timeStamp_nonce: timeStamp_nonce,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  };
const payload = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(msg)).toString('base64');
const signature = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(payload, secret));
console.log("Payload:", payload)
console.log("\nSignature:",signature)
```

I tried to convert:

```
let timeStamp_nonce = Date.now().toString();
let bodystring = `{"ID":"001"}`
const body = JSON.parse(bodystring)
const secret = "secret"
const msg = {
    timeStamp_nonce: timeStamp_nonce,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
};
const payload = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(msg));
//
// confused on this part...
//
//const signature = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(payload, secret));
//
//
Logger.log("Payload:", i)
Logger.log("\nSignature:",signature)
```

Can anyone help with this to run in Google Apps script

Comment: Read [mcve]....

Comment: The solution from the answer is certainly the best option here. But CryptoJS can also be used in Google Apps Script, because it's a _pure_ JavaScript library. Of course you're not allowed to use NodeJS statements, which the posted code does when Base64 encoding. But this wouldn't be necessary at all, because the same can also be achieved with CryptoJS onboard means: `const payload = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(JSON.stringify(msg)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert the script of Node.js in your question to Google Apps Script.

I think that this conversion can be achieved using the built-in functions of Google Apps Script. Please check the following sample script.

#### Sample script:

```
let timeStamp_nonce = Date.now().toString();
let bodystring = `{"ID":"001"}`
const body = JSON.parse(bodystring)
const secret = "secret"
const msg= {
  timeStamp_nonce: timeStamp_nonce,
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
};
const payload = Utilities.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(msg));
const bytes = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_512, payload, secret);
const signature = bytes.map(b => ('0' + (b & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
console.log("Payload:", payload)
console.log("\nSignature:",signature)
```

#### Result:

When `timeStamp_nonce` is `"1234567890123"`, your script of Node.js returns the following values.

```
Payload: eyJ0aW1lU3RhbXBfbm9uY2UiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzIiwiYm9keSI6IntcIklEXCI6XCIwMDFcIn0ifQ==

Signature: bd291d4c05e1a217afd90e2036fad2f3273ed4e4eada909fe5878cf2e902849ec5b01b160e20d8f43b0564be83e4a74391ccd280d43771a12a1363e5458ad61d
```

I could confirm that about this result, when `timeStamp_nonce = "1234567890123"` is used for above above Google Apps Script, the same result could be obtained.

#### Note:

- At Google Apps Script, the value which is encrypted by `Utilities.computeHmacSignature` is the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal. In this case, in order to achieve the conversion, it is required to convert the bytes array to the unsigned hexadecimal.
- Please use above Google Apps Script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [computeHmacSignature(algorithm, value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsignaturealgorithm,-value,-key)
- [Enum MacAlgorithm](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/mac-algorithm)